# Xcode 10 - Scroll View is not allowing scrolling when adding button programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm getting data from a database and trying to display the data as buttons, I have got this working but when I run the app on the Xcode simulator the buttons are showing and I can see they are off the screen but I can't scroll.

I have tried adding a "view" inside the "scroll view" with a fixed height and then adding the buttons to that view and still nothing.

```swift
// Adding the scroll view and the view
@IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var content: UIView!


// Button Settings
var buttonX = 100
var buttonY = 0
let buttonWidth = 200
let buttonHeight = 50
let image = UIImage(named: "button") as UIImage?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for element in contentsArray {
         // Adding a button for each client name
         let button = UIButton(type: .system)
         button.setTitle(element, for: .normal)
         button.tintColor = .white
         button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 22)
         button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
         button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)      
         button.frame = CGRect(x: buttonX, y: buttonY, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)

         content.addSubview(button)

         buttonY = buttonY + 70
    }
}
```

I am not getting any errors in the console when running the app.

Comment: you have to set scroll content size `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 700)`

Answer (score 0):

Once your finish adding buttons, set the scrollView.contentSize.height to your calculated `buttonY`

```
scrollView.contentSize.width = self.view.frame.size.width // non scrollable content width
for element in contentsArray {
     ...
     buttonY = buttonY + 70
}
scrollView.contentSize.height = buttonY // scrollable content height
```